# Launch two processes simultaneously and collect results from the process finished earlier

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I want to run two commands `c1` and `c2`, which essentially process (but not modify) the same piece of data on Linux.

Right now I would like to launch them simultaneously, and see which one finishes quicker, once one process has finished, I will collect its output (could be dumpped into a file with `c1 >> log1.txt`), and terminate the other process.

Note that the processing time of two process could be largely different and hence observable, say one takes ten seconds, while the other takes 60 seconds.

=======================update

I tried the following script set but it causes infinite loop on my computer:

```
import os


os.system("./launch.sh")
```

`launch.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm /tmp/smack-checker2
mkfifo /tmp/smack-checker2

setsid bash -c "./sleep60.sh ; echo 1 > /tmp/run-checker2" &
pid0=$!
setsid bash -c "./sleep10.sh ; echo 2 > /tmp/run-checker2" &
pid1=$!

read line </tmp/smack-checker2
printf "Process %d finished earlier\n" "$line"
rm /tmp/smack-checker2
eval kill  -- -\$"pid$((line ^ 1))"
```

`sleep60.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 60
```

`sleep10.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run 2 processes and make them write to the shared named pipe
after they finish.  Reading from a named pipe is a blocking operation
so you don't need funny `sleep` instructions inside a loop.  It would
be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkfifo /tmp/run-checker

(./sleep60.sh ; echo 0 > /tmp/run-checker) &
(./sleep10.sh ; echo 1 > /tmp/run-checker) &

read line </tmp/run-checker
printf "Process %d finished earlier\n" "$line"
rm /tmp/run-checker
kill -- -$$
```

sleep60.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 60
```

sleep10.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 10
```

**EDIT:**

If you're going to call the script form Python script like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
os.system("./parallel.sh")
print("Done")
```

you'll get:

```
Process 1 finished earlier
./parallel.sh: line 11: kill: (-13807) - No such process
Done
```

This is because `kill -- -$$` tries to send TERM signal to the process
group as specified in `man 1 kill`:

> -n
>
> where n is larger than 1.  All processes in process group n are
>          signaled.  When an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it
>          is meant to denote a process group, either a signal must be
>          specified first, or the argument must be preceded by a '--'
>          option, otherwise it will be taken as the signal to send.

It works when you run parallel.sh from the terminal because $$ is a
PID of the subshell and also of the process group.  I used it because
it's very convenient to kill parallel.sh, process0 or process1 and all
their children in one shot.  However, when parallel.sh is called from
Python script `$$` does not longer denote process group and `kill --`
fails.

You could modify parallel.sh like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkfifo /tmp/run-checker

setsid bash -c "./sleep60.sh ; echo 0 > /tmp/run-checker" &
pid0=$!
setsid bash -c "./sleep10.sh ; echo 1 > /tmp/run-checker" &
pid1=$!

read line </tmp/run-checker
printf "Process %d finished earlier\n" "$line"
rm /tmp/run-checker
eval kill  -- -\$"pid$((line ^ 1))"
```

It will now work also when called from Python script.  The last line

```
eval kill  -- -\$"pid$((line ^ 1))"
```

kills pid0 if pid1 finished earlier or pid0 if pid1 finished earlier
using ^ binary operator to convert 0 to 1 and vice versa.  If you
don't like it you can use a bit more verbose form:

```
if [ "$line" -eq "$pid0" ]
then
    echo kill  "$pid1"
    kill  -- -"$pid1"
else
    echo kill  "$pid0"
    kill -- -"$pid0"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that when I execute your code with `os.system` in a Python script, it always reports "kill: no such process"...

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: This somehow causes infinite loop.

Comment: It works here, can you post the entire shell script and Python script you use?

Comment: No, it does not work on my computer. Let me update my question. Thanks a lot for your kind help!

Comment: You write to /tmp/run-checker2 but read from /tmp/smack-checker2.
This will prevent `read` from returning.

Comment: Oh, gee! Sorry for the annoying message. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `wait -n` to wait for either process to exit. Ignoring race conditions and pid number wrapping,

```
c1 & P1=$!
c2 & P2=$!
wait -n  # wait for either one to exit
if ! kill $P1; then
  # failure to kill $P1 indicates c1 finished first
  kill $P2
  # collect c1 results...
else
  # c2 finished first
  kill $P1
  # collect c2 results...
fi
```

See `help wait` or `man bash` for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Can this snippet give you some idea?

```
#!/bin/sh

runproc1() {
  sleep 5
  touch proc1    # file created when terminated
  exit
}

runproc2() {
  sleep 10
  touch proc2    # file created when terminated
  exit
}

# remove flags
rm proc1
rm proc2

# run processes concurrently
runproc1 &
runproc2 &

# wait until one of them is finished
while [ ! -f proc1 -a ! -f proc2 ]; do
  sleep 1
  echo -n "."
done
```

The idea is to enclose two processes into two functions which, at the end, touch a file to signal that computing is terminated. The functions are executed in background, after having removed the files used as flags. The last step is to watch for either file to show up. At that point, anything can be done: continue to wait for the other process, or kill it.

Launching this precise script, it takes about 5 seconds, then terminates. I see that the file "proc1" is created, with no proc2. After a few seconds (5, to be precise), also "proc2" is created. This means that even when the script is terminated, any unfinished job keeps to run.